# SQL Server composite unique key performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2012, database-performance

I have 6 columns where I want to apply composite unique key for prevent duplication, is it safe as performance respect?

Consider we will perform CRUD on behave of that 6 composite keys.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a concept of a "unique key" - and you don't need to create a primary-key to enforce uniqueness: that's what a `UNIQUE INDEX` is for.

Comment: As far as performance is concerned, that depends on what operations you're performing, the host server's specs, the scale of data (millions, billions of rows?), and the actual indexes you're creating.

Comment: max data will be 100k in update but that table might have 10million records

Comment: First of all, you need to split your DB into OLAP (for individual analytical processing) or OLTP (for batch transactions). In case you want to go for a key which is expected to identify rows uniquely based on multiple keys as you mentioned, you need to go for a SK(Surrogate Key) which will uniquely identify each row.

Comment: @Dai `SQL Server doesn't have a concept of a "unique key"` - https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/144/5203

Comment: @GSerg My mistake! I forgot that a `UNIQUE` can now be the target of a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether an index with six columns is "safe", then it is perfectly fine.  If your data model wants the combination of the six columns to be unique, then a unique index or unique constraint (which is implemented using a unique index) is how this is enforced.

There is overhead to an index -- whether it has one column or six.  Generally, the cost is low enough to not be an issue.  And the gains in data integrity and faster queries outweigh cost.

Do note that there is a limit to the overall size of the keys for *any* index.  If your data values exceed that size, then you will not be able to maintain the index.

Comment: Even though it's implemented through an index, to be correct this is about adding a unique *constraint* to the database model.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, I will make your answer as accepted if no other answer will come in a day.

Answer (score 0):

> composite unique key on 6 columns

It depend upon real example.First thing come to mind is whether how this table is Normalize,or Denormalize ?

It also depend upon each column data type,and how each combination are populated.

This will be really very wide index.Cost of index will increase.

There will be very high Index fragmentation.

So not only cost of CRUD will increase,Select query will also suffer.

Because of high index cost ,optimizer will often choose Index Scan.

However, if you create `Clsutered index` on `INT Identity` column.

This will improve your CRUD performance.

Then Create `Composite Unique keys` with most selective column first.
In other word order of columns in composite index is important.